# How to enable the export to 'csv' in visual studio

Tags: reporting-services

One of my colleagues is not able to export to CSV from the Visual studio. He is not getting the option to export to 'CSV' what I am getting on below screen shot.

[image]

We are using VS 2010 Devloper Edition.

[image]

We are not referencing to any report server as well.

[image]

I beileve we need to change in the report server config (RsReportServer.config) file for this but I am unable to find any report server config file in the local system.

We can see the reports having the export option in the report server but the problem with the local machine.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: locate the rsreportserver.config file by navigating to C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/MSRS[Version].[Instance]/Reporting Services/ReportServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a developer's Visual Studio environment, the rendering options can be found in this file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\RSReportDesigner.config